# Change Attribute value from 1 & 0 to Yes and No on Front End

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, default-values

I have an attribute whose value when input was 1 & 0, 1 = yes and 0 = no.

I have just upgraded to `Magento 1.9.2` and on the front end, it is showing **1 & 0**, instead of **Yes or No**.

Is there a simple coding I can do that will put **Yes and No** on the frontend instead of **1 & 0**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add you code which you have used for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data == "1"){
echo "Yes";
}else{
echo "No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $attrVal ? "Yes" : "No"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

on frontend you have to write following code for that attribute.

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
```